# Filtrar os pontos no map [javascript]

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

Olá

Eu tenho um select no meu site que serve como filtro, e eu gostava de fazer desaparecer pontos específicos no mapa dependendo do filtro escolhido.

É possível associar os pontos feitos no mapa ao meu json? se sim como é que posso fazer isso?

O json está a fazer trabalho de base de dados.

Os pontos no mapa foram criados através de script

É possivel dar um id a um script e colocar o id na pessoa especifica do json?

===========================================================================

Código do select + mapa:

```js
var map;
                function initMap() {
                  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: 38.736946, lng: -9.142685},
                    zoom: 7,
                    });
                    
                    var image = '/imagens/iconmapa2.png';

// Lagoa, algarve
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 37.147150, lng: -8.483230},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// ilha terceira, Açores
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 38.721210, lng: -27.210329},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Almada, pragal
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 38.667440, lng: -9.179570},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Terrena, alandroal
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 38.621020, lng: -7.411580},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Terrena, alandroal - segunda vitima
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 38.621020, lng: -7.411580},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Dafundo, Oeiras
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 38.706230, lng: -9.250460},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Travessa das Frigideiras, Santarém
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 39.235370, lng: -8.682080},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Moimenta da Beira, Viseu
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 40.985050, lng: -7.617740},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Cruz de Pau, Seixal
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 40.668580, lng: -7.933170},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Cruz de Pau, Seixal - Segunda vitima
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 40.668580, lng: -7.933170},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Porto
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 41.157944, lng: -8.629105},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Golegã, Santarém
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 39.402700, lng: -8.489080},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Salamonde, Vieira do Minho
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 41.681510, lng: -8.091410},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

// Ventosa, Torres Vedras
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 39.067570, lng: -9.309280},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
  }
  
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6BWOev4iy16PGYkfagX-s07yLGO92hLk&callback=initMap"></script>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    var json = [{
        "Nome": "Lucia Rodrigues",
        "Idade": 48,
        "Distrito": "Faro",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": 46,
        "Distrito": "Açores",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Vera Silva",
        "Idade": 30,
        "Distrito": "Setúbal",
        "Faixa Etaria": "26-35",
        "Faixa": "faixaC",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Maria Eufrázia",
        "Idade": 83,
        "Distrito": "Évora",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Luzia Rosado",
        "Idade": 80,
        "Distrito": "Évora",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Fernanda",
        "Idade": 70,
        "Distrito": "Lisboa",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": 48,
        "Distrito": "Açores",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Marina Mendes",
        "Idade": 25,
        "Distrito": "Viseu",
        "Faixa Etaria": "18-25",
        "Faixa": "faixaB",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Helena Cabrita",
        "Idade": 60,
        "Distrito": "Madeira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Lana",
        "Idade": 2,
        "Distrito": "Madeira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "0-17",
        "Faixa": "faixaA",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Fernando Cruz",
        "Idade": 60,
        "Distrito": "Porto",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Masc",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Ana Maria Silva",
        "Idade": 53,
        "Distrito": "Açores",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Ana Paula",
        "Idade": 40,
        "Distrito": "Braga",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Heila Lopes",
        "Idade": 44,
        "Distrito": "Lisboa",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    }
    ]
    
    $(document).on("click", "#btnBuscar", function() {
  var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
  var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
  var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
  var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

  var arrayResultados = json.filter(function(item) {
    var criteria = true;

    if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
    if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
    if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
    if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

    return criteria;

  });
  
  $(document).on("click", "#btnLimpar", function() {
  $('#selectsfiltro').each (function(){
    this.reset();
  });

  var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
  var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
  var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
  var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

  var arrayResultados = json.filter(function(item) {
    var criteria = true;

    if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
    if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
    if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
    if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

    return criteria;

  });
```

```html
<div id="escolha">
<form id="selectsfiltro">
    <h6>Faixa Etaria:</h6>
    <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">0-17</option>
        <option value="2">18-25</option>
        <option value="3">26-35</option>
        <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/> 
    <h6>Sexo:</h6>
    <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="5">Masc</option>
        <option value="6">Fem</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Recurso a arma:</h6>
    <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="7">Sim</option>
        <option value="8">Não</option>
    </select>


    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Localidade:</h6>
    <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
        <option ></option>
        <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
        <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
        <option value="11">Bragança</option>
        <option value="12">Braga</option>
        <option value="13">Porto</option>
        <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
        <option value="15">Viseu</option>
        <option value="16">Guarda</option>
        <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
        <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
        <option value="19">Leiria</option>
        <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
        <option value="21">Santarém</option>
        <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
        <option value="23">Évora</option>
        <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
        <option value="25">Beja</option>
        <option value="26">Faro</option>
        <option value="27">Açores</option>
        <option value="28">Madeira</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br>

    <div class="botesdefiltrar">
        <button id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Filtrar</button>
        <button type="reset" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Limpar Filtro</button>
  </div>   
  </div>
  
  <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Tem de fornecer código para poderem ajudar no seu problema.
O que já tentou?

Comment: @MauroAlmeida vou editar a pergunta e por lá o codigo que tenho

Comment: @MauroAlmeida coloquei o codigo, pode dar uma olhada? o que não intender diga! eu so queria associar uma localização do mapa a um caso do json com algum codigo que desconheço, como se fosse uma class de html ao css percebe?

Comment: Você está querendo muita coisa em uma só pergunta. Experimente fazer uma pergunta para cada caracterísitca que você precisa.